# How would I compile text like this?

Tags: text, compilation

I figured this would be the place to ask this. I'm trying to get text to be read by a program, but it needs to be compiled like the attached image to be readable. I could not find any resources online for this, though that is probably because I am not using the right key words. If this is not the place to ask these questions, please point me in the right direction as I have no idea what I am doing.

[image: the text in compiled form]

I tried searching for the way this is compiled, but I don't think I have the right key words to find what I am looking for.

Comment: All that can be said about that "text" in the image isn't any "text". It's a binary file of some kind. Where did you get it from? What documentation about it do you have access to? What is your actual assignment?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).